# Create method complex type comes always null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple application to test asp.net core and when we test the Create Method the entity always comes null.

Follow the codes

[image]

```
@model PluralsightTestCore.Models.Beer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Beer</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nome" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net Core 2 API POST Objects are NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862459/asp-net-core-2-api-post-objects-are-null)

Comment: My app is not a API.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the tag helpers are working?

Comment: Hi Kirk, please, how can I do that? thks

Comment: Check your developer tools and see what data is being sent to the server. Perhaps the names aren't being set correctly.

Comment: I don't know whats happening, I create another project with a MVC template and everything works. This projects (with error) was a Empty template...Maybe missing something. Thks.