# ASP Core 2 empty POST request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, http-post

I've got a simple HTTP POST request, which I send to an ASP Core 2 application running in localhost with Kestrel. The received data is always `null` unless I use `PostAsJsonAsync` from another C# app.

The `json` I'm sending has this form:

```
{
  "_isValid": true,
  "_username": "test",
  "_guid": "f3f574eb-5710-43c5-a4ff-0b75866a72a7",
  "_dt": "2018-02-11T15:53:44.6161198Z",
  "_ms": "IsSelected"
  [...]
}
```

The ASP controller has this form:

```
// POST: api/NativeClient
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]string value)
{
   [...]
```

**1. Case: sending with `PostAsJsonAsync` from another C# app**

In one case I'm successfully sending the request via another separate C# application which uses `PostAsJsonAsync` like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://localhost:51022/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/NativeClient/", json);
```

The controller receives the call and populates `value` successfully.

**2. Case: sending with an external REST client like Postman**

In another case I try to send the request via another REST client, such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or Visual Studio Code through [REST client extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client):

```
POST http://localhost:51022/api/NativeClient/ HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "_isValid": true,
  "_username": "gnappo",
  "_guid": "f3f574eb-5710-43c5-a4ff-0b75866a72a7",
  "_dt": "2018-02-11T15:53:44.6161198Z",
  "_ms": "IsSelected"
  [...]
}
```

Here the request is received by the controller, but the `string value` is always `null`.

I've tried removing the `[FromBody]` tag, checking the request header, checking the json string in the body (which is exactly the same), and other things mentioned in the references below, but nothing works.

What am I missing?

---

**Other tests tried/references**

[Value are always null when doing HTTP Post requests](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2202)

[Asp.net Core 2 API POST Objects are NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862459/asp-net-core-2-api-post-objects-are-null)

[Model binding JSON POSTs in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST request needs to declare that the sent data is `text/plain`. Using the example with `HttpClient`:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
```

This way, your API will be able to receive your JSON as a `string` content.

If instead you want to receive your content deserialized into the original model object, you need to add this header into your request:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

and change your controller to:

```
// POST: api/NativeClient
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]yourClass class)
{
   [...]
```

Send `JSON` object to your `API`:

```
var Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/NativeClient/", Content);
```

---

`PostAsJsonAsync` takes a C# Object as an input; it serializes it as a `JSON` string before sending it.
Instead, `PostAsync` can take a `JSON` string to send.

see this Q&A [httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158378/httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp)

see this links for more info:

[PostAsJsonAsync in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx)

[PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128123(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I already had `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")` set in my separate C# application. If I change the controller API in `Post([FromBody] YourClass classValue)`, however, I'm able to get `classValue` only if I send a `POST` request through Postman; if I use `PostAsJsonAsync` then `classValue` results `null` again. Any idea?

Comment: I see you too like @Roma edited to suggest that I swap my `PostAsJsonAsync` into a `PostAsync`, and change my controller signature to use my Model class instead of a `string`. While both your answer work, I'm struggling to understand why my original solution didn't work for both types of HTTP call. Would you like to elaborate? Many thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You should deserialize `JSON` to some model (class), because I believe you deserialize this string anyway somewhere in your code:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public bool _isValid { get; set; }
    public string _username { get; set; }
    public string _guid { get; set; }
    public DateTime _dt { get; set; }
    public string _ms { get; set; }
    // other properties from json
}
```

And your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] YourModel value)
```

**Regarding to your app:**

In your app you pass `json` as argument to `PostAsJsonAsync()`, but you need to pass object and it will be parsed to `JSON`:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/NativeClient/", yourObject);
```

`yourObject` is instance of class which should be parsed to `JSON`.

**After comment:**

Also, try to change your app code to:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://localhost:51022/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");    
var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/NativeClient/", httpContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do this, I'm able to use Postman and `YourModel value` gets correctly populated, but then the `PostAsJsonAsync` does not work anymore: I receive `null`. Any idea here?

Comment: @alexlomba87, do you post same `JSON`?

Comment: Your suggestion of using `PostAsync` instead of `PostAsJsonAsync` worked. To recap, I changed the signature of the controller including the `YourModel` insted of a `string`, then swapped the HttpClient method `PostAsJsonAsync(json)` into `PostAsync(new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`. Thanks. Would you like to elaborate why it didn't work originally? I think it would be useful to have an explanation in the answer.

Comment: @alexlomba87, see edit, `PostAsJsonAsync()` should work now